# How do I stop Notes requiring a new password every time I open it?

Tags: lotus-notes

How do I stop Lotus Notes 8.5 requiring a new password every time I open it? If I close Notes the next time I open it asks for a new password.

Comment: In the default configuration, it's supposed to ask for your password every time.  Is this how it's always been, and is it the same for your co-workers? Or are you asking because it's a change in behavior, or different than your co-workers?

Comment: Isn't your ID file write protected?

Answer (score 2):

Post a screenshot of the login box you are getting and I may be able to be more specific, but I assume it's asking for a new password because you have the option checked to login to Notes using your OS password, and your Notes password doesn't match so it's trying to get you to change it so they sync up.

The preference for this is in file-->security-->user security-->security basic, 'Log in to Notes using your operating system login'